# How does the content root path work in .NET 6?

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-6.0

I have a project that requires retrieving files from outside itself on the server its hosted on. For now, I'm just grabbing a Javascript file but it will eventually grab other things. I tried out changing the content root path in Program.cs to allow this and it worked beautifully. But I noticed that the original relative links to Javascript and css files still worked without any changes.

For example this path, "~/css/site.css", still works despite changing the content root path and not telling it to specifically look in my project's own wwwroot folder. The external file must use a more specific path. For example: "~/some-other-project/wwwroot/js/myscripts.js".

Now this is all fine and actually preferred behavior but I want to know *why* it's working this way. Does the project check its own wwwroot folder first before looking elsewhere in the folder specified in the content root path? I want to understand the behavior behind this so I can feel more confident in using this method.

EDIT:
Here is a repo with as an example: https://github.com/love-bird-13/Custom-Content-Path-Test
The first commit is just setting up two basic .Net 6 projects without any changes. The second commit contains all the changes I made to reproduce what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About your question

> Does the project check its own wwwroot folder first before looking elsewhere in the folder specified in the content root path?

The [Serve files outside wwwroot by updating IWebHostEnvironment.WebRootPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?#serve-files-outside-wwwroot-by-updating-iwebhostenvironmentwebrootpath) topic specifies below.

> When `IWebHostEnvironment.WebRootPath` is set to a folder other than `wwwroot`
>
> - In the `development` environment, static assets found in both `wwwroot` and the updated `IWebHostEnvironment.WebRootPath` are served from `wwwroot`.
> - In any environment other than `development`, duplicate static assets are served from the updated `IWebHostEnvironment.WebRootPath` folder.

So the behavior you describe is applicable while in `development` environment mode.

You'll notice that when [changing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments) the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable to something else than `Development` - which is the default while developing - the files in `wwwroot` won't be served anymore.

---

That same topic gives some approaches for below scenarios.

1. In case you want static content to only be served from the customized path instead of the default `wwwroot`, then the easiest might just be to delete that `wwwroot` folder.
2. In case you want to combine `wwwroot` with a custom folder, then you add an additional `app.UseStaticFiles` in `Program.cs`; here below `Assets` is a custom folder with some static files, but it can be any absolute path that is reachable.

   ```
   app.UseStaticFiles();

   app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
   {
       FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
           Path.Combine(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, "Assets")
           // Or some other absolute path. 
       )
   });
   ```

Answer (score 1):

This is explained in the docs in the [web root](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=windows#web-root) section:

> The web root is the base path for public, static resource files, such as:

> - Stylesheets (.css)
> - JavaScript (.js)
> - Images (.png, .jpg)

> By default, static files are served only from the web root directory and its sub-directories. The web root path defaults to `{content root}/wwwroot`.

And

> In Razor `.cshtml` files, `~/` points to the web root. A path beginning with `~/` is referred to as a virtual path.

Comment: My web root does not point to my specific wwwroot folder though. It is the same as the content root.

Comment: @Tuskle can you please elaborate and share a [mre]?

Comment: Sorry for the wait, I've updated my question with an example repo. If you run it you will find that app 1 will be able to fetch the test.css from app 2 but no changes are necessary to the other scripts referenced in app 1's layout page. I'm interested in knowing why this is.